# Translate a Javascript function to Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I'am newbie in Python and i'am having a hard time trying to translate this Javascript arrow function into Python. I'am not able to make the part where i use substring in JS to get the next 3 values in my loop when i find '\x1D'. Any tips or suggestions ?

```
module.exports = edi => {
  let decompressedEdi = ''
  let lastCompressor = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= edi.length; i++) {
    if (edi[i] === '\x1D') {
      let decimal = parseInt(edi.substring(i + 1, i + 3), 16)
      let repeater = edi[i + 3]
      decompressedEdi +=
        edi.substring(lastCompressor, i) + repeater.repeat(decimal)
      lastCompressor = i + 4
    }
  }
  decompressedEdi += edi.substring(lastCompressor, edi.length)
  return decompressedEdi.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')
}
```

Comment: What does this code do? Could you also show your attempt/how far you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, strings can be sliced like arrays :

```
for i, c in enumerate(edi):
  if c == '\x1D':
    decimal = int(edi[i+1:i+3], 16)
```

The int function has the following signature: int(str, base)

Comment: how will you make the loop then to get [i+1:i+3] ? edi is a string. If i write: for i in edi: if i == '\x1d': decimal = int(edi[i+1:i+3], 16) I'll get an error since i is a string, not an integer

Comment: @MaximeMorin-Gagnon De ce que j'ai compris de ta question, tu ne savais pas comment t'y prendre pour faire le substring. C'est pourquoi j'ai omis la boucle et la declaration de `i`.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas enumerate, merci pour la solution

Answer (score 1):

```py
from re import sub

def decompress(edi):
    decompressed = ""
    last_compressor = 0

    for i, c in enumerate(edi):
        if c == "\x1D":
            repetitions = int(edi[i + 1: i + 3], 16)
            repeating_char = edi[i + 3]

            decompressed += edi[last_compressor:i] + repeating_char * repetitions
            last_compressor = i + 4

    decompressed += edi[last_compressor:-1]

    return sub("\r\n|\n|\r", decompressed)
```

---

### How I read the code

> Feel free to ignore this bit, but it might help.

Given `edi` which has a `len`, for each `edi` that matches `\x1D`, get the substring of `edi` from the `index + 1` to `index + 3` as a hexadecimal integer as set as `decimal`. The `repeater` is the `index + 3`'th element of `edi` for each element and it is expected to be a `str`. It will be repeated the hexadecimal number of times defined in `decimal`, but only after the substring of `edi` from `lastCompressor` to the current index. On each iteration where `\x1D` is matched, the `lastCompressor` is increased by 4.

Comment: Might run into some encoding issues here, but this should be a good start.

Comment: Its gonna help for sure, thx